# Twilio Laravel "Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_URL - assumed 'CURLOPT_URL' in CurlClient.php line 111"

Tags: php

Looking for some debug suggestions and/or help. I'm not very familiar with installing PHP modules or packages, and not at all familiar with curl/curl extensions. Is there a way to identify what extensions are installed for curl? This is assuming that's the problem, and not some incompatibilities! Any help/advice is appreciated.

I'm using the Twilio Laravel package twilio/sdk (5.12), and trying to create a Client to retrieve call details (Programmable Voice service only). My Twilio account info is being passed to create the client (exactly as depicted in the docs), but it fails with this message:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_URL - assumed 'CURLOPT_URL'
in CurlClient.php line 111
```

I am able to create a Client on my machine (MacOS), with just a few variations on the relevant system/package versions.

I contacted Twilio support, and they suggested I'm

> missing the proper curl extension with the version of curl that you have on your machine

They provided this link, but the instructions did not resolve the problem: [sms-twilio-api-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493391/sms-twilio-api-errors-in-command-line-but-no-errors-in-the-browser-but-not-sendi). 
I get the same exact error, even after restarting apache, clearing the Laravel config:cache, etc.

When I try to reinstall or upgrade curl or php-curl, the server informs me that

```
curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13).
```

**SERVER:**

- curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- cURL support => enabled
- PHP 7.2.21-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
- Laravel 5.7

**LOCAL:**

- curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0)
- cURL support => enabled
- PHP 7.1.21
- Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when you check the version of PHP by `php-v`, you assume everything is updated and well, if it shows the newest version.

Then when you install cURL by `apt-get install php-curl` and it installs the newest version, you assume that you're a step closer to cURL heaven and everything is going to be okay.

What you really need to do, is check if your Apache instance has ONLY the newest version of PHP enabled and loaded. In my case, despite everything being updated, Apache was still loading PHP7.1 instead of 7.2. This is no way for things to be, but it is what it is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

1. `apachectl -M`
2. Check if `php7_module` is listed
3. > `sudo a2dismod php7.1`
4. `apachectl -M` to see if `php7_module` is gone from the list
5. > `sudo a2enmod php7.2`
6. Verify if loaded with `apachectl -M`
7. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Feel free to play around with the php version in step 3 - try php7.0, php7.2, etc. Disable everything, before enabling the newest version.